# Comparison of Javascript Pattern/Paradigms / Best practice of design

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, paradigms

I am compiling a list of biases(both proponents and antiponents) to explain to my team lead why our current javascript design is outdated. This is an open-ended question, I am looking for 3rd party analysis on the pro's and con's of the following to paradigms.

Our existing paradigm on the system looks like the following

```
var class= (function () {

    var property1 = 8;

    var method2 = function (value) {
        var instance = this;
        return value;
    };

    var method1 = function () {
        var instance = this;
        return "Hello";

    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            alert(methodTwo(methodName()));
            method2();
            console.log(state);
        },
        method1: function(){
            method1();
        }
    }

})();
```

I want to convince him of the following as a best practice

```
namespace.MyClass = function(){
 var instance = this;
 instance.Property1 = 8;
 instance.Method1 = function(){};
 instance.Method2 = function(){};
}
var myobject = new namespace.MyClass();
```

Comment: Your "best practice" is outdated as well. Use ES6 `class` syntax :-)

Comment: How is the `instance` variable supposed to be used? It doesn't appear to be working at all in your current pattern. Please either post real code, or a description of the generic purpose of your pattern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is open-ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately Invoked Function Expressions:

- +Scope Protection
- +Works on older browsers

Ecmascript 6:

- +Modern standard
- -No compatibility for ie 8 and lower

PseudoObjectOrientated:

- +More OO orientated
- +Delayed invocation
- -Overuses reliance on instance of "this pointer"